# GridBagLayout being flagged as error

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
>>>import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
public class GridBagLayout {
    public static void createWindow(){
        JFrame aWin = new JFrame("Title");
        aWin.setBounds(0,0,200,200);
        aWin.setVisible(true);

        GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        >>>aWin.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBag);


        constraints.weightx = constraints.weighty = 10.0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        addButton(" Press ",constraints,gridBag,aWin);
        constraints.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    }
    static void addButton(String label,GridBagConstraints constraints,GridBagLayout layout,JFrame window){
        JButton button = new JButton(label);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        >>>layout.setConstraints(button,constraints);
        window.getContentPane().add(button);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                createWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The lines marked with >>> are flagged as error by Eclipse IDE.
The error for `import java.awt.GridBagLayout;` states that there is a possible conflict with the type within the same file
The error for `aWin.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBag);` states that GridBagLayout can not be applied although when I tried FlowLayout, it was fine.
The error for `layout.setConstraints(button,constraints);` states that the method is undefined.
What is the cause for this error? Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile error pretty much describes the problem. Simply rename your class to, say, GridBagLayoutTest.

Answer (score 2):

These are caused by the fact that you named your class `GridBagLayout`.  You need to either change the name of your class or use explicit full path for all uses of the `java.awt.GridBagLayout` class and not use an import for it.